# Lumen ->withErrors($validator)

Tags: php, validation, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to display all errors in div.

**Controller**

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')->withErrors($validator->errors);
}
```

**View**

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        {{ $error }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

**And I get:**

Undefined variable: errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need this:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('/')->withErrors($validator->errors());
}
```

Note the function call to `errors()` instead of referencing a variable.

In order to use this, you must enable sessions by uncommenting the middleware within the `$app->middleware()` method call in your `bootstrap/app.php` file.

Comment: Do you get that error in your controller or in your view?

Answer (score 3):

`$errors` was undefined in views for me too, until I uncommented the following lines in `bootstrap\app.php`:

```
$app->middleware([
     Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
     Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
]);
```

Currently the Lumen documentation on validation tells you that the $errors variable is **always** available in your views. Apparently that's not the case when you use it 'out of the box'.